# Add CARingBuffer to project

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio, xcode9

I seem to have a problem adding the CARingBuffer.h and CARingBuffer.cpp to a project I am doing in XCode9. I am trying to write an example from the book "Learning Core Audio" by  Chris Adamson. I don't seem to have the folder /Extras and tried to locate the CoreAudio folder but couldn't do it. I have added the CoreAudion framework to the project, but adding the .h file directly is not recognised by XCode.

```
#include "CARingBuffer.h" << doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download Apple's CoreAudio utility classes from:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Introduction/Intro.html

See the folder /CoreAudio/PublicUtility in the archive for the classes you need.